# dividing columns by 99th percentile in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas dataframe.
df

```
LeafId  pidx    pidy    count    value
1       10      20       2         5
1       10      35       10        10
1       10      26       30        15
1       10      40       11        20
1       15      20       25        25
1       30      70       12        30
1       40      20       27        35
```

i am looking to normalize the `count` and `value` column by dividing the values with the 99th percentile of that column.
and after the division it the value exceeds 1 make it as 1.

what i am trying is

```
count_quantile_99 = df['count'].quantile(.99)    #finding 99th percentile of count & storing in variable
    value_quantile_99 = df['count'].quantile(.99)    #finding 99th percentile of value & storing in variable

df['count'] = df.count.div(count_quantile_99 )
df['value'] = df.value.div(value_quantile_99)
```

I dont know whether this is the right approach.
 also looking for any other better way to find 99th percentile.

Also whenever my value in column `count` and `value` Greater than `1`
how to make it 1

Comment: is `quantile` a method?

Comment: @RohanAmrute yes. i googled it and found, but also lokking for any other better way to find 99th percentile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrame.clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html):

```
df1 = df[['count', 'value']]
df[['count','value']] = df1.div(df1.quantile(.99)).clip_upper(1)
print (df)
   LeafId  pidx  pidy     count     value
0       1    10    20  0.067069  0.144092
1       1    10    35  0.335345  0.288184
2       1    10    26  1.000000  0.432277
3       1    10    40  0.368880  0.576369
4       1    15    20  0.838364  0.720461
5       1    30    70  0.402414  0.864553
6       1    40    20  0.905433  1.000000
```

Comment: ! wow, i didn't knew about clip_upper(). i was naive and was trying to it by `df['count'].replace(df['count'][df['count'] >1 ], 1)` after dividing it by 99th percentile :P

Comment: Yes, it is nice method with [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) and 
[`clip_lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html).

Comment: what i thought was first getting quantiles for `count and value` and store them in a variable `count_quantile_99` and then divide.
in your method it automatically divides each column  by 99th percentile of that column itself?

Comment: I think it is same, but my variable is called `df1`

Comment: Accepted :) i was just concerned, if my df is very huge then again i am creating df1 , might cause some memorry issue n all. but apart from that the solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: `clip_upper` for the win!

Comment: @jezrael hey! if i want to add another column called as score/ or repalce count,value column to `score` column where score is count+ value+LeadID
`df['score'] = df.count.add(df.value,df.LeafID)` would work?

Comment: @SRingne - I think the simplier is use `sum` like `df['new'] = df1.div(df1.quantile(.99)).clip_upper(1).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @SRingne I think better is `df['new'] = df[['LeafId','count','value']].sum(axis=1)` if need `count` and `value` columns  too.

Comment: @jezrael Sir, you are GOD. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
d1 = df[['count', 'value']]
d1 = d1.div(d1.quantile(.99))
df.update(d1.where(d1 < 1, 1))

print(df)

   LeafId  pidx  pidy     count     value
0       1    10    20  0.067069  0.144092
1       1    10    35  0.335345  0.288184
2       1    10    26  1.000000  0.432277
3       1    10    40  0.368880  0.576369
4       1    15    20  0.838364  0.720461
5       1    30    70  0.402414  0.864553
6       1    40    20  0.905433  1.000000
```